# MemoryError of running Randomforest in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am following the `Python` example given in [For Beginners - Bag of Words](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words). However, the following code segment gives the error message like `MemoryError`. What might cause this error

```
forest = forest.fit(train_data_features, train["sentiment"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Project3/demo4.py", line 60, in <module>
   forest = forest.fit(train_data_features, train["sentiment"])
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-        
   packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 195, in fit
X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-
   packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 341, in check_array
   array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryError`, as the name says, means you're running out of free memory.

If you're following the example code from [here](https://github.com/wendykan/DeepLearningMovies/blob/master/BagOfWords.py), then there are a few things that could help you:

- delte variables using `del` when you don't need them anymore
  (for example, `clean_train_reviews` is not needed after line 62)
- After line 42, only `train["sentiment"]` is needed, the rest of `train` could be discarded to free memory
- don't read both the training and the test sets at the beginning. The `test` set is only needed after building the forest, and at that point nothing else related to the train set is needed anymore.
- The whole training part could be wrapped in a function returning the forest, that would take care of all references which are no longer needed after that.

Comment: Following your advice, I've created doTrain() function to allow Python to clean variables. It alone solves the `MemoryError` in my run of this tutorial. OS: Ubuntu 14.04, RAM 8G

Answer (score 0):

In the specified example the bag of words contains 5000 features; this requires significant memory. So, one solution is to reduce the number of features, but doing this may affect the model performance.
Another solution is to switch from 32-bit Python to 64-bit.